# Issue with policy-based autosign in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am trying to implement policy based autosign in puppet. I have performed following steps:

**On puppet master**:

- I have created a ruby utility to autosign the certificate if matching the extension specified in csr_attributes.yaml on puppet agent then exit 0 otherwise return exit 1.
- I have give the ruby utility executable permission for all the users.
- Specified the ruby utility full path in [master] section of puppet.conf on master server. This is what I have set:

  autosign = $confdir/certsign.rb

**On puppet agent**

- Created the file /etc/puppet/csr_attributes.yaml with the contents:

  extension_requests: pp_uuid: abcdefghijk

Now when I run `puppet agent -t` it is throwing the error and not auto signing the CSR:

`Error: Could not request certificate: Error 400 on SERVER: Invalid pattern "first line of script"`

How do I fix this error?